# VueJS App put data from GET request inside an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

This is my script of a VueJS component which should show data inside a dashboard.

```
<script>
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
//import stockInit from "highcharts/modules/stock";

//stockInit(Highcharts);
exportingInit(Highcharts);

export default {
  props: {
    partsdata: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(data => {
        var result = JSON.parse(data) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        console.log(result.Fare) // eslint-disable-line no-console
      })
    }
  },
  components: {
    highcharts: Chart
  },

  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        series: [{
          data: [] // sample data
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Receiving the data from my backend works fine, but I am unable to get it into the chart. I still struggle how to work with async tasks, so I tried this and failed

```
this.data.push(result.Fare)
```

> Header.vue?5e07:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'push' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.eval (Header.vue?5e07:34)

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Update: This is my template where I trigger the Method:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="fetchData" class="btn-primary">Get Data</button>
    <highcharts
      :options="chartOptions"
    ></highcharts>

  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code if you're trying `this.data.push` its understandable that its telling you its undefined. 
To get to your data prop in your fetchData method youd have to use 
`this.chartOptions.series[0].data.push`
I'm not sure where you're firing fetchData either in that code. Try move it to your created/mounted methods in the vue lifecycle, you can then change your chartOptions to a computed or watcher, setting data in the data() method and calling it in your chartOptions with this.data.

**UPDATE:**
On click is fine for your get request if it's firing keep that the same, its where you're then setting it thats the issue.
I refactored your request, if its successful when you test it response.data should give you the results you need, not sure why you need to parse it unless its returning a json blob as a string? 
I also added a `v-if` to your chart renderer, if `this.data` is empty then don't render. See how you get on with that.

```
import { Chart } from "highcharts-vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
//import stockInit from "highcharts/modules/stock";

//stockInit(Highcharts);
exportingInit(Highcharts);

export default {
  props: {
    partsdata: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data/')
      .then(response => {
        this.data.push(JSON.parse(response.data))
      })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    data: function() {
     this.chartOptions.series[0].data.push(this.data)
    }

  },
  components: {
    highcharts: Chart
  },

  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
      chartOptions: {
        series: [{
          data: [] // sample data
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <button @click="fetchData" class="btn-primary">Get Data</button>
            <highcharts if="data.length > 0" :options="chartOptions" ></highcharts>

        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that already helps a lot. I updated my question to show you where I trigger my GET Request. Can you tell me how to update that to display the data in the chart?

Comment: Not far away I guess, thank you! One issue if still left: Result is the observer Object, not the acutal array

[__ob__: Observer]
0: Array(1)
0:
1: 71.2833
2: 7.925
3: 53.1
4: 8.05

Comment: Not sure what that is given the question you've asked if my answer resolved that issue I'd mark it as completed and accepted and ask another if it's related to a specific API you're getting data from. I'd need to know more information to help resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly get data and change chartOptions:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts class="hc" :options="chartOptions" ref="chart"></highcharts>
    <button @click="fetchData" class="btn-primary">Get Data</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/ztyb0')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.chartOptions.series[0].data = data;
      })
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        series: [{
          data: []
        }]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-05mpo

**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue